# Multiple LIKE's in query with 2 LEFT JOINS

Tags: php, mysql, sql

EDIT: Strange I vardumpped every variable they are all a bool(false)

I'm trying to make this query. But when I click the search button nothing shows up.
Someone who can direct me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

```
                   $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM artikel
                                LEFT JOIN barcode
                                ON artikel.barcode_id = barcode.barcode_id
                                LEFT JOIN debiteur
                                ON artikel.debiteur_id = debiteur.debiteur_id 
                                WHERE debiteur.debiteur_naam LIKE '%$formulier%'
                                AND artikel.artikel_leverancier LIKE '%$leverancier%'
                                AND artikel.artikel_leverancier_code LIKE '%$artikelleverancier%'
                                AND artikel.artikel_code LIKE '%$artikelexact%'
                                AND artikel.artikel_omschrijving LIKE '%$artikelomschrijving%'
                                ORDER BY '$orderby' ASC");
```

Comment: Provide your data and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Does the page function correctly otherwise?  Does your search return valid (although empty) results or does it have errors?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I'm trying to search through table 'artikel' and 'debiteur'. I only have 2 rows in the table I'm just testing. But for example when I type  'a' in the search field $artikelomschrijving it doens't return anything though the first letter in a row from artikel_omschrijving is a.

Comment: @SuperJer The page functions correctly. It returns valid but indeed empty.

Comment: Do you have nullable foreign keys in one or more tables?

Comment: @SpaceApple No I haven't

Comment: You might want to change the left joins to inner joins. Also have a look at @Ghazanfar Mir solution.

Comment: `LIKE` on something that starts with a wildcard `%` is a (potential) performance killer. MySQL can't use any indexes for those columns. (It's like an index in a dictionary, that is also not useful when you want to find all words that *contain* the letter `q`.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are interested in items which satisfy atleast one LIKE condition, you need to replace `AND`s with `OR`s

```
  $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM artikel
                    LEFT JOIN barcode
                    ON artikel.barcode_id = barcode.barcode_id
                    LEFT JOIN debiteur
                    ON artikel.debiteur_id = debiteur.debiteur_id 
                    WHERE debiteur.debiteur_naam LIKE '%$formulier%'
                    OR artikel.artikel_leverancier LIKE '%$leverancier%'
                    OR artikel.artikel_leverancier_code LIKE '%$artikelleverancier%'
                    OR artikel.artikel_code LIKE '%$artikelexact%'
                    OR artikel.artikel_omschrijving LIKE '%$artikelomschrijving%'
                    ORDER BY '$orderby' ASC");
```

Comment: I changed the ANDs to ORs. The output didn't turn blank this time it shows everything.

Comment: What exactly do you want to get in result of the query?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have to test for empty parameters.  Here is one way in SQL:

```
WHERE ('$formulier' <> '' and debiteur.debiteur_naam LIKE '%$formulier%') or
      ('$leverancier' <> '' and artikel.artikel_leverancier LIKE '%$leverancier%') or
      ('$artikelleverancier' <> '' and artikel.artikel_leverancier_code LIKE '%$artikelleverancier%') or
      ('$artikelexact' <> '' and artikel.artikel_code LIKE '%$artikelexact%') or
      ('artikelomschrijving' <> '' and artikel.artikel_omschrijving LIKE '%$artikelomschrijving%')
```

Alternatively, you can build up the query clause by clause when the variables are not empty.

Comment: Strange I vardumpped every variable they are all a bool(false)